# Simplifing double integral with known function(s)

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals, special-functions, trigonometric-integrals

I want to know if we can simplify the following double integral
$$
I = \int_0^{\pi}dx\int_0^{2\pi-x}dy\sqrt{1+4\cos{x}\cos{\frac{y}{3}} + 4\cos^2{\frac{y}{3}}}.
$$

I have tried to simplify it, but failed. 
I do not expect to find a closed-form of it (its numerical value is $\approx$23.3110) because it seems to be impossible for me (how about you?). 
However, it would nice if someone could point out whether $I$ is a transcendental number or not.
I also wonder that if it is possible to transfer it to a single integral, like $I = \int_a^b dx\rho(x)$ where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, and $\rho(x)$ is the kernel function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Let $\mathcal{I}$ denote the following double integral:

$$\mathcal{I}:=\int_{0}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{2\pi-x}\mathrm{d}y\,\sqrt{1+4\cos{\left(x\right)}\cos{\left(\frac{y}{3}\right)}+4\cos^{2}{\left(\frac{y}{3}\right)}}.$$

The trigonometric expression under the radical is easily seen to be nonnegative for all real arguments by rewriting it in the form

$$\begin{align}
1+4\cos{\left(x\right)}\cos{\left(\frac{y}{3}\right)}+4\cos^{2}{\left(\frac{y}{3}\right)}
&=\sin^{2}{\left(x\right)}+\left[\cos{\left(x\right)}+2\cos{\left(\frac{y}{3}\right)}\right]^{2}\ge0,\\
\end{align}$$

and so the value of $\mathcal{I}$ is a well-defined positive real number, and according to WolframAlpha it has an approximate numerical value of

$$\mathcal{I}\approx23.311.$$

---

We can rewrite $\mathcal{I}$ as a double integral of an algebraic function over a rectangular region after the following manipulations:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}
&=\int_{0}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{2\pi-x}\mathrm{d}y\,\sqrt{1+4\cos{\left(x\right)}\cos{\left(\frac{y}{3}\right)}+4\cos^{2}{\left(\frac{y}{3}\right)}}\\
&=9\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{\frac{2\pi}{3}-x}\mathrm{d}y\,\sqrt{1+4\cos{\left(3x\right)}\cos{\left(y\right)}+4\cos^{2}{\left(y\right)}};~~~\small{\left[\left(x,y\right)\mapsto\left(3x,3y\right)\right]}\\
&=9\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\mathrm{d}x\int_{x-\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\sqrt{1+4\cos{\left(3x\right)}\sin{\left(\varphi\right)}+4\sin^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}};~~~\small{\left[y=\frac{\pi}{2}-\varphi\right]}\\
&=9\int_{-\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\mathrm{d}\theta\int_{\theta}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\sqrt{1-4\sin{\left(3\theta\right)}\sin{\left(\varphi\right)}+4\sin^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}};~~~\small{\left[x=\theta+\frac{\pi}{6}\right]}\\
&=9\int_{-\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\theta}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\sqrt{1-4\sin{\left(3\theta\right)}\sin{\left(\varphi\right)}+4\sin^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}};~~~\small{\left[\left(\theta,\varphi\right)\mapsto\left(-\theta,-\varphi\right)\right]}\\
&=\frac{9}{2}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\int_{\theta}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\sqrt{1-4\sin{\left(3\theta\right)}\sin{\left(\varphi\right)}+4\sin^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{9}{2}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\theta}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\sqrt{1-4\sin{\left(3\theta\right)}\sin{\left(\varphi\right)}+4\sin^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}}\\
&=\frac{9}{2}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\sqrt{1-4\sin{\left(3\theta\right)}\sin{\left(\varphi\right)}+4\sin^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}}\\
&=\frac32\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\theta\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\sqrt{1-4\sin{\left(\theta\right)}\sin{\left(\varphi\right)}+4\sin^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}};~~~\small{\left[\theta\mapsto\frac13\theta\right]}\\
&=\frac32\int_{-1}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{-1}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{\sqrt{1-4tu+4u^{2}}}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}\sqrt{1-u^{2}}};~~~\small{\left[\left(\theta,\varphi\right)=\left(\arcsin{\left(t\right)},\arcsin{\left(u\right)}\right)\right]}.\\
\end{align}$$

Finally, the double integral $\mathcal{I}$ can be reduced to the one single-variable integral,

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}
&=\frac32\int_{-1}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{-1}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{\sqrt{1-4tu+4u^{2}}}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}\\
&=\frac32\int_{-1}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\int_{-1}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\sqrt{1-4tu+4u^{2}}}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}\\
&=3\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\int_{-1}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\sqrt{1-4tu+4u^{2}}}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}\sqrt{1-u^{2}}};~~~\small{\left[\left(t,u\right)\mapsto\left(-t,-u\right)\,\text{symmetry}\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{3}{\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}\int_{-1}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\sqrt{4u^{2}+1-4ut}}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{3}{\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{\sqrt{\left(2u+1\right)^{2}-8uw^{2}}}{\sqrt{1-w^{2}}};~~~\small{\left[t=2w^{2}-1\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{2}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{6}{\sqrt{4-x^{2}}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{\sqrt{\left(x+1\right)^{2}-4xw^{2}}}{\sqrt{1-w^{2}}};~~~\small{\left[u=\frac12x\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{2}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{6\left(1+x\right)}{\sqrt{4-x^{2}}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{\sqrt{1-\left[\frac{4x}{\left(1+x\right)^{2}}\right]w^{2}}}{\sqrt{1-w^{2}}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{2}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{6\left(1+x\right)}{\sqrt{4-x^{2}}}\,E{\left(\frac{2\sqrt{x}}{1+x}\right)},\\
\end{align}$$

where the complete elliptic integral of the second kind $E$ is defined here by the integral representation,

$$E{\left(\kappa\right)}:=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}t^{2}}}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}};~~~\small{-1\le\kappa\le1}.$$

---

I suspect there's more progress to be made here if we keep at it, but that's all I got for now at least...

Cheers!